# Is it a memory leak in the following C code?

Tags: c, memory-leaks

Is it a memory leak in the flowing C code?

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 int *a;

 int main() {
      a = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
      return 0;
 }
```

Comment: No, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, your code leaks a block of the size of ten integers. However, since it exits right away, the memory is returned back to the OS, so nobody is going to notice except valgrind.

Comment: To get a leak you need to have it in a function that is called in a long loop.

Comment: Define what you mean by "leak"

Comment: If nothing else you should use static memory for this kind of thing, it will improve performance and make your application safer.

Comment: Hi, Vality. This code is just used to get this "leak" thing clear.

Comment: a memory leak, irregardless of the duration, is when a call to malloc(and family) allocates memory and that memory is not properly released via a call to free().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At least the way most people use the term, the answer would be yes--any memory allocated by the program and never freed is considered a leak.

At the same time, most people are concerned primarily with *progressive* leaks--ones that can/will leak progressively more memory as a program runs, for example from doing an allocation inside a loop, and failing to free that memory.

Especially for something that really needs some memory to remain allocated for the entire life of the program anyway, the difference between freeing before exit and leaving the memory allocated until exit is complete becomes more a question of hair-splitting than a truly useful distinction. Some view it as a travesty to leave the memory allocated, even if it's only freed immediately before exit. Others view it as a waste of code (and invitation to bugs) to explicitly free memory immediately before exit (when any competently designed OS will regain the process' resources anyway).

Comment: I am writing a static analyzer to detect memory leaks. I'm wondering whether or not to report a warning in such a case.

Comment: @ZhaopengLi: I'd say yes, at least allow reporting it--but probably allow the user to disable reporting if desired, especially if every run results in a small, constant set of blocks being leaked. Leaks that vary between runs are probably more interesting as a rule.

Comment: thanks for your constructive advice. In our tool, currently each run results in the same result. (There is no random path chosen)

Answer (score 2):

since the program exits as soon as it allocates then linux (or windows) will automatically `free` that memory space so there is no leak but you were to do stuff after `malloc` and before the program ends then there will be a leak

Comment: Memory allocated by `malloc` that isn't explicitly `free`d isn't guaranteed to be reclaimed by the OS - such behavior is not required by the C standard. However, I won't downvote this because you mention linux and windows.

Answer (score 2):

This will be reported by valgrind and Intel Inspector as memory leaks as the memory allocated is not freed. However, it may possible that this may not have an impact on the program.

If this allocated memory is required till the exit of the program, then this leak warning can be avoided. But design must specify that not freeing will not lead to other problems like out of memory. For example, there might be some singleton instance of a controller object which must be present as long as program runs.

However, if such allocations are lost and never used and design does not consider them, then it is definitely a leak.

Now, in your case, this allocated memory is used no where. Hence, such allocations must be considered as leaks.

It might possible that OS takes away all the memory when program exits. This must not be taken for granted when application has to run for a long time (like server applications) and will exists for a very long and will have lots of maintenance in the future.

Comment: Before I posted this question, I am a little confused. Now, I think I am clear on this topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a memory leak in your program. You are allocating a memory of size 10*4 [ consider int takes 4 bytes ] and you are not freed the memory. To avoid memory leak you must free the allocated memory.

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int *a;

    int main()
    {
         /* allocating the Memory */
         a = malloc( sizeof (int) *10 );
         /* free the allocate memory */
         free ( a );
         return 0;
    }
```